# Fatal Error Using Google PHP Client Library

Tags: php, google-api, google-analytics-api

I'm using [Google's PHP client library](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/) to access the [analytics API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/platform/features/cost-data-import) and I keep getting an error, **Call to a member function on a non-object**. I've been stumped for more than a day. I've read through [several solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Call+to+a+member+function+on+a+non-object), and I'm not seeing how to resolve this.

```
require_once "google-api-php-client/src/Google_Client.php";
require_once "google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_AnalyticsService.php";
session_start();

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("app-name");
$client->setClientId('client-id');
$client->setClientSecret('my-secret');
$client->setRedirectUri('http://www.website.com/');
$client->setDeveloperKey('secret-key');

$analyticsService = new Google_AnalyticsService($client);
$dailyUploads = $analyticsService->dailyUploads;
```

This is (I *think*) the way that [Google recommends](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/source/browse/trunk/src/contrib/Google_AnalyticsService.php#31) to set this up, yet when I print out the contents of $dailyUploads its empty/null. If I print out $analyticsService I see the code of Google_AnalyticsService.

Later in my code, after authentication, I attempt to use the upload function like so:

```
$upload = $dailyUploads->upload($media);
```

This produces the error that I mentioned earlier, Fatal error: Call to a member function upload() on a non-object.

Can anyone help? What am I overlooking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've now resolved this. There were two issues:

1. The Google_AnalyticsService.php file has been updated since the most recent stable release, so the code that I linked to wasn't actually loaded in my project. I resolved this by updating my library to include the code displayed on [their website](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/source/browse/trunk/src/contrib/Google_AnalyticsService.php#31).
2. The correct way to refer to the class is 'management_dailyUploads'. I updated my code as such.

   $analyticsService = new Google_AnalyticsService($client);
   $dailyUploads = $analyticsService->management_dailyUploads;

   $upload = $dailyUploads->upload('123456', 'UA-123456-1', 'xXxXxXxX', 2013-02-15, 1, 'cost', array("reset" => true, "data" => file_get_contents('/path/to/file.csv'), "mimeType" => 'application/octet-stream', "uploadType" => 'media'));

Once I implemented these updates my app started communicating with Google's servers. I now have a different issue to solve (don't we always?), but the question that prompted this thread has been resolved so I'll mark this as answered.

ps - I don't know why the code didn't format correctly here.